# Getting button text value when clicked (Python and Selenium)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using the below two functions to click a button based on the text on the button's label. Instead I would like to be able to identify the button's text value when the user clicks on it. I can't use Xpath, as this will be used for online store product pages to click "Add to cart." Since each product page has a different Xpath, identify it by the text on the button's label is (To my knowledge) the most reliable way.

Is there a way to either return the text of the button when clicked so I can pass it to this function, or is there a more reliable way to do what I'm attempting?

To give an example, the button on a page says "Add to cart." I would like to be able to return "Add to cart" when the user clicks the button. That way I can use that value to identify the button in the future when the user is on a different product page.

```
def GetElementByText(driver, text):
    element_dict = { }
    element_dict['xpath'] = "//*[.='" + text + "']"
    element_dict['element'] = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[.='" + text + "']")))
    print(element_dict['element'])
    return element_dict

def ClickButton(driver, element_dict):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_dict['xpath']))).click()
    return
```

Comment: I would say not because Selenium doesn't deal with user's clicking. But it can return a webelement's text when grabbed with .text.

Comment: I did use .text and was unable to grab the text that way. I'll look into it more. Is there another library that can handle doing that?

Comment: Not that I know of currently.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can also use other methods to find the button, like class name, tag name, css selector etc. to get the text, you need to find the element and then either take .text or .get_attribute("whatever the attribute is called")

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of get_attribute, but I can't figure out how to return all of the attributes of the element. Is there a way to return a directory of all the possible attributes to select?

Comment: You would have to check the docs, but idts, but the button name should always be the same, like ("href") or ("class")